# 3 Month Old Baby Falls Asleep After Crying At Night - Should We Wake Them Again To Feed?

Tags: infant, sleep, feeding

This just happened to me and I've been trying to find an answer online to no avail.

My son started crying a little bit ago, so we started to heat up a bottle. Both my wife and I had to use the master restroom for a moment, and by the time we were done and the bottle was ready, our son was back asleep.

I wasn't sure though if we should have woken him up again to take his feeding and diaper changing, or if letting him continue to sleep was the right thing to do.

He is 3 and a half months old, and we think he is either going through a growth spurt or starting his first tooth, so the wakeup may have been related to either growing pain instead of hunger, but we're still not sure if we should have picked him up and tried to feed him anyway - should we have?

Comment: Also you'll get accustomed to the 'type' of cry. My daughter had this cry that we used to call 'complaining', where she'd sound like a grumbling old lady. She especially did it when she was tired and was falling asleep. We learned to leave her to complain because it was just her way of falling asleep (obviously after ensuring all of her needs were met before bedtime)

Answer (score 7):

It’s obviously too late to change anything, but if I were you, I wouldn’t worry.

If he just woke up and fell asleep again, no harm done, a normal-weight baby at that age doesn‘t need to be woken up to be fed at night - when they are hungry or otherwise uncomfortable they will let you know.

If it happens again, you *may* be on the way to the coveted “sleeping through the night” stage - or not. There’s a lot of variance and that’s perfectly fine. Rest assured, if he was truly hungry, he would either have stayed awake or woken up again soon after. As for his caloric needs, if you are feeding on demand, he’ll be fine and let you know how much he needs.

Comment: My concern here is that he *was* crying initially, then stopped after some time. Should we have tried to feed him while he was sleeping if that is the case?

Comment: In my opinion - no need.

Comment: babies cry, it's one of their 4 primary functions. If he was in discomfort he would not have gone back to sleep. Think of the cry as an, "Where am I? What's going on? Oh I'm in a safe place in bed, fine I'll go back to sleep"

Answer (score 3):

The same thing happened to my son around the 3 month mark. He fell asleep while I was making his bottle. I opted to wait it out. He surprisingly lasted 3 hours longer the first time (sleeping 9 hours instead of 6), effectively skipping a bottle.

Since then, it's been a roll of the dice. Sometimes you get only a few minutes out of him, sometimes and hour or two, on average about half an hour.

Until 2-3 months, babies *must* be fed regularly, sleepy or not. But after that, you can start letting them decide the pace, at least at night. Exceptions made if your baby is behind the curve weight-wise; talk to your pediatrician in that case.

Answer (score 0):

My baby too used to cry when he passes urine and stops very soon and sleeps again . Sometimes he also cries or smiles in sleep and stops once he hears our sound.If he is truly hungry he cries until he is fed.So I think you no need to wake him up again.